# Finding Green's function for $\Omega$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

I'm studying differential equations and I am asked to find Green's function for $\Omega$ = {$(x,y)$ $\in \mathbb{R^2}$: $x^2+y^2 < r^2, y>0$ }. I've looked around places such as [here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/greensfcns.pdf) but am having a hard time figuring out where to start. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Idea: You know the Green's function for the unit disk. Now find a conformal map between $\Omega$ and the unit disk, and pull back the Green's function.

Comment: can you further elaborate please?